Getting 404 Error when passing params to URL using Chi router in Golang
I'm trying to pass url parameter into endpoint but getting 404 page not found error when trying to run test or send request via Postman.
My method with routes:
func NewListRoutes(
    r *chi.Mux,
    log *slog.Logger,
    jwt *jwtoken.TokenService,
    usecase port.ListUsecase,
) {
    c := &listController{
        logger:  log,
        jwt:     jwt,
        usecase: usecase,
    }

    // Protected routes
    r.Group(func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Use(jwtoken.Verifier(jwt))
        r.Use(jwtoken.Authenticator())

        r.Route("/user/lists", func(r chi.Router) {
            r.Get("/", c.GetListsByUserID())
            r.Post("/", c.CreateList())

            r.Route("/{list_id}", func(r chi.Router) {
                r.Get("/", c.GetListByID())
                r.Put("/", c.UpdateList())
                r.Delete("/", c.DeleteList())
            })
        })
    })
}

My test:
func TestGetListByID_HappyPath(t *testing.T) {
    u := url.URL{
        Scheme: "http",
        Host:   host,
    }
    e := httpexpect.Default(t, u.String())

    // Register user
    r := e.POST("/register").
        WithJSON(model.UserRequestData{
            Email:    gofakeit.Email(),
            Password: randomFakePassword(),
        }).
        Expect().
        Status(http.StatusCreated).
        JSON().Object()

    accessToken := r.Value(jwtoken.AccessTokenKey).String().Raw()
    t.Log(accessToken)

    // Create list
    c := e.POST("/user/lists/").
        WithHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken).
        WithJSON(model.ListRequestData{
            Title: gofakeit.Word(),
        }).
        Expect().
        Status(http.StatusCreated).
        JSON().Object()

    listID := c.Value("data").Object().Value("id").String().Raw()

    t.Log(listID)

    // Get list by ID
    getListResp := e.GET("/user/lists/{list_id}").
        WithPath("list_id", listID).
        WithHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken).
        Expect().
        Status(http.StatusOK).
        JSON().Object().NotEmpty()

    t.Log(getListResp.Raw())
}

=== RUN   TestGetListByID_HappyPath
    printer.go:57: POST http://localhost:8082/register
    get_list_test.go:31: 
    printer.go:57: POST http://localhost:8082/user/lists/
    get_list_test.go:45: 2gqBx2IyOcrXwvJi97stAdpdpIG
    printer.go:57: GET http://localhost:8082/user/lists/2gqBx2IyOcrXwvJi97stAdpdpIG
    reporter.go:24: 
            
            Error:          
                            unexpected http status value
                            
                            test name: TestGetListByID_HappyPath
                            
                            request: GET /user/lists/2gqBx2IyOcrXwvJi97stAdpdpIG HTTP/1.1
                              Host: localhost:8082
                              Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Im9nemoxTEhQZHdfY1V1S1p1TVF0a1hKTkxHaz0iLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEsImVtYWlsIjoibGVyYXRlcnJ5QGJyZWl0ZW5iZXJnLmluZm8iLCJleHAiOjE3MTY0MTYzNjksImlzcyI6InNzby5yc2hlbGVraG92LmNvbSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiIyZ3FCeDBUOE83cllrczJvaFBLdkJNNkpGOWkifQ.mZPy2cnp133IJs78AjL_B5q17vkIKtfWBHH0F8hLDTsYWHhAQ8CDgI7QwmusnNNR6ktkrouhncp53IMDoGi7NACbtWigA22K2XIZXJOKMKYzVGAUEkCV3gdFeDnWWX9-isyPXZvH1YS_XXjaqrjsEgQWRIl7Kd1j8M9vLTjiHoJJU3eWTADrxe5BJWvFZ9286ePJKUVWoCrm1fN3Xi_i7U9QL2FLVTYwa-9Q6BOo5d1hHtjfgS6HoRA3y6-EpIC2DLfxO78CgU6Pwpore8TrkAvqTK2yIzV7jPUgrM5dWjxaxZt4aQAy_aSYqJWGPUMthrJg_5_ZXk-uFa6sCKXnUw
                              Cookie: refresh_token=2gqBwxbSh7ZUo3UlCHKWarn0KQd
                            
                            response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 228.666µs
                              Content-Length: 19
                              Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
                              Date: Wed, 22 May 2024 22:04:29 GMT
                              X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
                              X-Ratelimit-Limit: 100
                              X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 98
                              X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1716415500
                            
                            assertion:
                              Request("GET").Expect().Status()
                            
                            expected value:
                              "200 OK"
                            
                            actual value:
                              "404 Not Found"
            Test:           TestGetListByID_HappyPath
    get_list_test.go:55: map[]
--- FAIL: TestGetListByID_HappyPath (0.13s)

In logs I see that other requests work correctly (registering user, creating list), but with url param I have this issue.
What I did wrong?
UPD.
Everything works ok if I use query parameters, but something goes wrong if I use the url param

Hey, would it work if it weren't paramater but a fixed path? You could just pass a dummy id to the grouped handlers to test that.

You could also remove r.Use(jwtoken.Verifier(jwt)); r.Use(jwtoken.Authenticator()) to see whether it makes a difference.

Hi @NotX, just tried to hardcoded listID and got the same result. It's weird for me because other routes in that group work correctly (I mean the route without url parameter). In other handlers (auth, for example) I also have subgroups (without url parameters) and it works. It seems to me that problem with url param — server can't find the route "user/lists/{list_id}" when I do request with an actual listID. But I checked examples, other issues with chi and even production code in one of my company's project and they have the same code examples for working with url params...

When remove middleware from that routes I get the expected error (500) because server can't find access token in the request

Tried to move handler out of protected route group:
r.Get("/user/lists/{list_id}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {   listID := chi.URLParam(r, "list_id")   w.Write([]byte("List ID: " + listID))  })
But continue getting error 404 page not found

Found a solution, but haven't quite figured out why it works that way yet. In my project I have this routes as well:
r.Group(func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Use(jwtoken.Verifier(jwt))
        r.Use(jwtoken.Authenticator())

        r.Post("/logout", c.Logout())

        r.Route("/user", func(r chi.Router) {
            r.Get("/", c.GetUser())
            r.Put("/", c.UpdateUser())
            r.Delete("/", c.DeleteUser())
        })
    })

And there was a conflict between routes and handlers for "/user" and "/user/lists/". I removed word "user" from routes for lists and everything works now:
r.Group(func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Use(jwtoken.Verifier(jwt))
        r.Use(jwtoken.Authenticator())

        r.Route("/lists", func(r chi.Router) {
            r.Get("/", c.GetListsByUserID())
            r.Post("/", c.CreateList())

            r.Route("/{list_id}", func(r chi.Router) {
                r.Get("/", c.GetListByID())
                r.Put("/", c.UpdateList())
                r.Delete("/", c.DeleteList())
            })
        })
    })


I think the order is important. Is  /user declared before /user/lists?

Yes, was declared before /user/lists

Now I refactored the structure a bit. Earlier I had a separate methods for initiating routes for each "domain" and then collected them in the newRouter() method. Now I have routes in one place (in a separate method initRoutes()), but my main AppRouter struct includes other routers for each "domain". I use a nested structs so that AppRouter can use the handlers of each of the nested routers. And now I finally can use routes like this /user/lists/{list_id}. If I understood correctly the problem was with attempting to mount a handler on an existing path
